# Reusing http headers

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find a best way to reuse http headers in my http responses. Instead of writing it in string literal

```
 final http.Response response = await http.post(APIPath.somePath(),
      headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization": "Bearer $_token"},
      body: json.encode(body));
```

I have made a custom class and get each header into a static function

```
class APIHeader {
  static Map<String, String> json() => {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
  static Map<String, String> form() => {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"};
  static Map<String, String> authorization(String token) =>
      {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"};
}
```

and call them wherever I need them which work great if there is only one header needed

```
  final http.Response response = await http.put(APIPath.somePath(),
      headers: APIHeader.json(), body: json.encode(body));
```

However I'm having a trouble if I need more then one header. I tried this..

```
final header = {}
  ..addAll(APIHeader.authorization(_token))
  ..addAll(APIHeader.json());
final http.Response response = await http.post(APIPath.somePath(),
          headers: header, body: json.encode(body));
```

which gives me an error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
```

Anyone have better idea how to reuse the headers?

Comment: `final header = {}` -> `final header = <String, String>{}`

Comment: @pskink Thanks... that worked for that error.. but is there any better way to reuse this headers? I found a bit tedious to initialise that header variable and then add those headers there.. Isn't there any better solution?

Comment: write a top level function that returns the map, or use `mergeMaps` for example (just found it one minute ago so i dont know how it works in practice)

Comment: @pskink Never heard of `mergeMaps`.. Where did you found it?

Comment: in the official flutter documentation

Comment: and if you want to merge more than 2 maps, use: `var maps = [{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}];
print(maps);
print(maps.reduce(mergeMaps));`

Comment: @pskink I must missing something because `mergeMaps` is not recognise by AS and not even DartPad. The documentation to the `mergeMaps` is just crazy and can't really figure out the point of it

Comment: `import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; var maps = [{1: 10}, {2: 20}, {3: 30}]; print(maps); print(maps.reduce(mergeMaps));
`

Comment: @pskink I found a solution to implement it into this case in my answer. Thanks for your help like always :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: I use **enums** to store headers :D why don't you give it a try.

Comment: @ChinkySight well sure but how about adding token into that enums.. You can't change or modify enum so you basically end up with bits and peaces of the headers which you will have to build together.. That isn't really convenience way of doing it. Or do you have any other trick with enums under the sleeve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink I found using `mergeMaps` from `'package:collection/collection.dart'` the best way to reuse headers and merge them into one map

```
 final http.Response response = await http.post(APIPath.somePath(),
      headers: [APIHeader.authorization(_token), APIHeader.json()]
          .reduce(mergeMaps),
      body: json.encode(body));
```